# Searching for photo in a windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I have installed Ubuntu on a laptop which was previously equipped with Windows (upgraded to 10). During Ubuntu installation, I did not delete Windows partition, notwithstanding that, following an update, windows boot was already not working properly.

Now I see my windows partition, from Ubuntu 16.04, as /media/marco/something.

Problem is, I want to recover files (photo, music) from a given windows user. I searched inside the various folder of the windows partition but it's not clear to me where I should find the data.

Could you help me in finding the correct path, from Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you know a portion of the file name?

Comment: Try looking for  /media/marco/something/user/"username"/pictures  or music

Comment: Print a list of ALL the files and directories with `find /media/$USER/something` pipe the result into `less` to see a page at a time (`... | less`).